# Kubernetes apiVersion extensions/v1beta1 fails regex validation

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I'm getting a weird regex validation failure for Kubernetes Api version - "extensions/v1beta1" while creating a deployment.

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=/var/go/.kube/mcc-pp-config --context=sam-mcc2-pp --namespace=sam-mcc2-pp apply -f k8s-config-sam-mcc2-pp/sf-spark-worker-deployment.yaml --record

Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "k8s-config-sam-mcc2-pp/sf-spark-worker-deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$'
```

This is the Kubernetes yaml that I'm using:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: sf-spark-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 30
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sf-spark-master
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sf-spark-master
        deployment: '$BUILD_VERSION'
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sf-spark-master
          env:
            - name: ENVIRONMENT
              value: '$ENVIRONMENT'
            - name: INIT_DAEMON_STEP
              value: 'setup_spark'
          image: '$DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST/salesiq-article-cache-stub:build-$BUILD_VERSION'
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 7077
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 6066
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: '$SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY'
              cpu: '$SPARK_MASTER_CPU'
```

The output for Kubectl version gives:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T18:44:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.7", GitCommit:"8eb75a5810cba92ccad845ca360cf924f2385881", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-27T09:42:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by following variables used in deployment YAML

```
$BUILD_VERSION
$SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY
$SPARK_MASTER_CPU
```

This is not the problem of `apiVersion` of *Deployment*.

It failed to read the value of these variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you use variable in your YAML, you can't use that YAML directly.

Its gives error, because of this `$` symbol.

But you can build your deployment from this YAML, you have posted in your question, with the help of `envsubst` command.

This command will replace your ENV variable in YAML.

Lets say, you have already set this ENVs,

```
$ export ENVIRONMENT="ENV_DATA"
$ export DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST="REGISTRY"
$ export BUILD_VERSION="TAG"
$ export SPARK_MASTER_MEMORY="5Gi"
$ export SPARK_MASTER_CPU="256Mi"
```

Now, substitute ENV variable and create `deployment.yaml` using following command

```
$ cat deployment.yaml | envsubst | kubectl create -f -
deployment "sf-spark-master" created
```

Hope this will help